# How to decode json in php coming from android json post volley

Tags: php, android, json

Gooday sorry for my bad english and a newbie in programming. I'm trying to decode a JSONObject thrown from an android volley JSON POST. Right now I'm able to received from the Android the response from the server and I can confirm that thru TOAST. My question is how to properly decode JSON from the server side using PHP. This JSON data will be use for inserting new data in MySQL. I just don't know the proper way and having hard time finding out the answer for the decoding setup for this. Please can you give any advice here.

```
public void testOrder (ArrayList<String> order_id,
                                      ArrayList<String> uname,
                                      ArrayList<String> prod_name,
                                      ArrayList<String> prod_id,
                                      ArrayList<String> quantity,
                                      ArrayList<String> branches,
                                      ArrayList<String> totalPrice,
                                      int itemIteration){
        JSONObject obj = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        final JSONObject finalobject = new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemIteration; i++) {
            obj = new JSONObject();
            Log.d("OBJECT_COUNTER", String.valueOf(i));
            try {
                obj.put("order_id",  order_id.get(i));
                Log.d("ORDER_ID",    order_id.get(i));
                obj.put("uname",     uname.get(i));
                Log.d("USERNAME",    uname.get(i));
                obj.put("prod_name", prod_name.get(i));
                Log.d("PROD_NAME",   prod_name.get(i));
                obj.put("quantity",  quantity.get(i));
                Log.d("PROD_QUANT",  quantity.get(i));
                obj.put("branch",    branches.get(i));
                Log.d("PROD_BRANCHES", branches.get(i));
                obj.put("totalPrice",  totalPrice.get(i));
                Log.d("TOTAL_PRICE",   totalPrice.get(i));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jsonArray.put(obj);
        }
            try {
                finalobject.put("ORDER_LIST", jsonArray);
                test = jsonArray.toString();
//                Toast.makeText(this,test,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.TRY_JSON_POST,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(PlaceOrder.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                       
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(PlaceOrder.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("tag", finalobject.toString());
//                String obj = finalobject.toString();
//                Toast.makeText(PlaceOrder.this,obj,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return params;
            }
        };
        AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(strRequest);
    }
}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$response = array("ORDERLIST" => $_POST["tag"]);
//$response = array($_POST["tag"]);
//$my_array = json_decode($response,true);

echo json_encode(str_replace('\"','"',$response));

     echo "RECEIVED";

} else{

       echo "nothing";
}
```

I use Log.d for the response:

D/Response:

```
{"ORDERLIST":"{\"ORDER_LIST\":[{\"order_id\":\"1755\",\"uname\":\"jordan\",\"prod_name\":\"ABC\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"branch\":\"Dapitan\",\"totalPrice\":\"23500\"},{\"order_id\":\"1755\",\"uname\":\"jordan\",\"prod_name\":\"AMD Kaveri A4-7300 APU HD8470D 2-Core 2GB 500GB CPU Package\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"branch\":\"Dapitan\",\"totalPrice\":\"23500\"}]}"}
```

After using echo $content this is displayed on my toast

```
D/Response: DATA:tag=%7B%22ORDER_LIST%22%3A%5B%7B%22order_id%22%3A%221755%22%2C%22uname%22%3A%22jordan%22%2C%22prod_name%22%3A%22ABC%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%2C%22branch%22%3A%22Dapitan%22%2C%22totalPrice%22%3A%2223500%22%7D%2C%7B%22order_id%22%3A%221755%22%2C%22uname%22%3A%22jordan%22%2C%22prod_name%22%3A%22AMD+Kaveri+A4-7300+APU+HD8470D+2Core+2GB+500GB+CPU+Package%22%2C%22quantity%22%3A%221%22%2C%22branch%22%3A%22Dapitan%22%2C%22totalPrice%22%3A%2223500%22%7D%5D%7D&
```

edited PHP code

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$content   = file_get_contents( "php://input" );
$response  = json_decode($content,TRUE);
$orderlist = json_decode($response['ORDER_LIST'], TRUE);

//echo $orderlist[0][order_id][0];

echo "DATA: ";

foreach($orderlist AS $row ){
  echo $row[uname];
} 

      echo $response;
} else{
      echo "nothing";
}
```

Comment: where is the json encoded response? in the array `$response['ORDERLIST']`?

Comment: it seems I cannot add photos yet. I can verify the response using toast from Android.

Comment: okay I have edited my post now and posted the respone using Log.d can you help me figure out how to decode this on php side. WIll really appreciate your help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works (I used it for many project but not with Android): otherwise I'll delete it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### (Edited)

Try this:

```
$content   = file_get_contents( "php://input" );
$response  = json_decode( $content, TRUE );
$orderlist = json_decode( $response['ORDERLIST'], TRUE );
```

From the PHP Documentation:

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives.

After decoding json data, you obtain in `$orderlist` an associative array. You can now choose to save to the database the array values you prefer.

So (i.e.): `$orderlist[0][order_id]` or `$orderlist[1][uname]`

Comment: I tried to echo $orderlist and $response and I don't get any value except the received echo response. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly. I also tried to echo $orderlist[0][order_id], but displays nothing from Android. Can you give me a code on how to access these decoded data and echo it so I can verify it more.

Comment: these decoded data are obtained through `json_decode( $content, TRUE )`; `$content` is assumed to be your 'echoed' response. 'echoed' how? The basic remains how you capture the original json data: neither `file_get_contents( "php://input" )` nor `$_POST` works?

Comment: I received a toast response using echo $content see my edit post. It is my first time to code JSON from Android passing it to PHP for insert of new data. So capturing the original json data is basically I do not know yet.

Comment: but you have tried with `file_get_contents( "php://input" )`?

Comment: @overdrive You cannot echo an array. You will only receive "Array ( )". If you want to dump an array to look at the structure, use `var_dump()`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I think he will receive "Array()" anyway, since he receive empty string for single array value...

Comment: I tried echo $content and yes it displays JSON format with special characters and also with var_dump($content). The file_get_contents( "php://input" ) is working but I just don't know how to properly access these arrays according to my JSON format.

Comment: This is amazing I can see the JSON format here. Can you give me a snippet on how to access these values in php. I've tried foreach but I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: yes you can use foreach( $orderlist as $row ) { echo $row[order_id]; (etc..) }

Comment: I posted edited php code I tried foreach but I can't get it to echo the value. It echoes nothing in my toast.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the data from this website 3v4l.org/LOKYe. Thanks for giving me this. Right now I'm receiving an error "Notice: Undefined index: uname in /in/iLt4r on line". I'm still trying to figure what is wrong.

Comment: @fusion3k my bad I forgot to put the index and even interchanged the index to the arrayname.